# Initial visible option in a drop down list used for filtering?

Tags: usability, gui-design, drop-down-list

I have a few dropdown lists used for filtering data in a grid. Initially the grid will show all the data and the user can select options from the dropdowns to filter by those selections.

Two questions:
1- What's a better option to indicate the dropdown has no selection? A blank option or something like '(View All)'? This will be the first option in the dropdown.

2- If the initial dropdown option is blank to indicate nothing is selected, would that confuse some users and make them think the dropdown is empty?

Comment: View all as default make lot of sense into that filter rather than keeping it empty

Comment: Can I select multiple options from drop-down list?

Answer (score 1):

**Consider having a default option that communicates what the user can expect to see in the dropdown.**

Neither of the suggested options helps user understand what the control is for. Using the default text to add context, adds visibility to the control and helps with differentiation.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI2wrn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: There's a label for each dropdown which indicates what the dropdown is used for. I am not sure if your suggestion is based on assuming there's no label. Although even with the label showing, 'filter by..'' seems to be better than a default blank selection or view all since view all doesn't mean the grid is showing all when other dropdowns might have selected options.

Comment: I did think about whether you might have labels. I assumed you did, and decided that having the additional information, especially when it describes the action (something I assume the label doesn't do), was going to be valuable regardless.

Comment: "_View all widgets_" and "_View all foobars_" would be another alternative; showing both what you _could_ filter by, _and_ that all are currently shown.